# How do I know when a byte is the first of a sequence of bytes representing MIDI delta time?

Tags: midi

I want to read and encode MIDI .mid files at the byte (and bit level). When reading through a .mid file, how do I recognize that a specific byte is the first byte of a delta time value?

For example, below is Figure 2.12 from Mandal's *Multimedia Signals and Systems* a diagram of a track chunk of a .mid file:

[image: Figure 2.12 from Mrinal Kr. Mandal's Multimedia Signals and Systems, 1st edition. Springer Science & Business Media]

How do I know that the `01`, `01`, `78`, `00`, `00`, and `00` are delta time bytes, given that the events they are attached to are of varying byte lengths? (For example, the instrument change appears to be two bytes beyond the delta time byte, while the first Note On event appears to contain 3 bytes beyond the delta time byte). Is it based on interpreting what follows the delta time byte? If so the fact that the second Note On event is throwing me: why does it appear to have only two bytes following the delta time byte?

It does not appear in Mandel's example, but I would appreciate an answer that clarified this for multi-byte delta times also.

And of course, I appreciate input on how to improve my question.

Finally, I am *not* asking for libraries that will automate reading .mid files. Those are good (yay!) but I want to understand the how to read the file format down to the byte level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have to decoce a MIDI message before you know where the next delta time begins.

The actual [Standard MIDI Files specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> ```
> <MTrk event> = <delta-time> <event>
> ```
>
> `<delta-time>` is stored as a variable-length quantity. It represents the amount of time before
>   the following event. If the first event in a track occurs at the very beginning of a track, or if
>   two events occur simultaneously, a delta-time of zero is used. Delta-times are *always* present.
>   […]
>
> ```
> <event> = <MIDI event> | <sysex event> | <meta-event>
> ```
>
> `<MIDI event>` is any MIDI channel message. Running status is used: status bytes of MIDI
>   channel messages may be omitted if the preceding event is a MIDI channel message with the
>   same status. The first event in each MTrk chunk must specify status. Delta-time is *not*
>   considered an event itself: it is an integral part of the syntax for an MTrk event. Notice that
>   running status occurs *across* delta-times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer CL. Everything after your first sentence I have already read in the spec. If you direct your attention to the second Note On event. I do not understand how I would know that the`00` following it is the delta time event, instead of the `43` in the middle of the first Note Off event. Is there an error in the second Note On? (Is it missing a `9n` byte? Is the `93` byte from the first Note On simply implicit for the second Note On? How do I decode the second Note On event to know that the `00` is the next delta time byte?)

Comment: Every note-on message has two parameter bytes. The missing status byte is what the specification calls "running status".

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful.